# Where do I find the machine epsilon in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, numerical-methods

The machine epsilon is canonically defined as the smallest number which added to one, gives a result different from one.

There is a `Double.Epsilon` but the name is very misleading: it is the smallest (denormalized) `Double` value representable, and thus useless for any kind of numeric programming.

I'd like to get the *true* epsilon for the `Double` type, so that not to have to hardcode tolerances into my program. How do I do this ?

Comment: Relevant: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/08/c-math-gotchas/

Comment: @AakashM: I read that. The meaning of epsilon is rather clear in view of IEEE754, and it is a shame that Microsoft did something this amateurish. Is their floating point implementation to be trusted ?

Comment: @AlexandreC.: `Double.MinValue` is most likely defined as it is to correspond to the other `MinValue` fields in the .NET Framework like `Int32.MinValue`, `DateTime.MinValue` etc. This obviously is not the same as `DBL_MIN` in C. However, I agree that the definition of `Double.Epsilon` is confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's(on my machine):

```
   1.11022302462516E-16
```

You can easily calculate it:

```
        double machEps = 1.0d;

        do {
           machEps /= 2.0d;
        }
        while ((double)(1.0 + machEps) != 1.0);

        Console.WriteLine( "Calculated machine epsilon: " + machEps );
```

Edited:

I calcualted 2 times epsilon, now it should be correct.

Comment: @Meonester Do you mean to divide machEps by 4 each time (once in the body and once in the condition?  If I leave out the condition division ( i.e. while ((double)(1.0 + (machEps)) != 1.0); ) I get a value for machEps of 1.11022302462516E-16.

Comment: @AlanT Right, which matches what the `Math.NET` code suggests it is.

Comment: Yes, you are right: Epsilon = 1.11022302462516E-16. There should be:
while ((double)(1.0 + (machEps)) != 1.0);

Comment: @Meonester Unless you're already in the process of doing it, you should then edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: A small nitpick/curiosity: This approach gives the correct answer from the perspective of the binary number itself, but if we're talking about the decimal literal then there's a smaller number that will produce the same binary representation. So, for example, on my machine the smallest *decimal* representation of the epsilon is actually `1.1102230246251566639E-16`. (Of course, `1.11022302462516E-16` and `1.1102230246251566639E-16` have *exactly* the same binary representation so are to-all-intents-and-purposes the same number.)

Comment: Wasn't it right the first time? When the loop terminates `(1.0 + machEps) == 1.0` which isn't what we want. We want the last value such that `(1.0 + machEps) != 1.0`.

Comment: After the last iteration it has to be doubled again so that machEps + 1 is actually different than 1. `machEps *= 2.0d;` should be added after the loop. And the result should be `2.22044604925031E-16`.

Answer (score 8):

The [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) library defines a [Precision](http://api.mathdotnet.com/Numerics/MathNet.Numerics/Precision.htm) class, which has a DoubleMachineEpsilon property.

You could check how they do it.

According to that it is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The base number for binary values
    /// </summary>
    private const int BinaryBaseNumber = 2;

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of binary digits used to represent the binary number for a double precision floating
    /// point value. i.e. there are this many digits used to represent the
    /// actual number, where in a number as: 0.134556 * 10^5 the digits are 0.134556 and the exponent is 5.
    /// </summary>
    private const int DoublePrecision = 53;

    private static readonly double doubleMachinePrecision = Math.Pow(BinaryBaseNumber, -DoublePrecision);
```

So it is `1,11022302462516E-16` according to this source.

Comment: It is quite complex bit fiddling, needing to know much more about the internal representation of `System.Double` that I am ready to tackle (it is not *just* IEEE754 stuff, but also endianness issues, etc).

Comment: @Alexandre: I'm pretty sure that the internal binary representation is mandated by IEEE-754 itself. There's a good description of the internals of `double` [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx). There's also a link to Jon's [DoubleConverter.cs](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) class in there too; looking at that might offer some clues.

Comment: @LukeH: Now that I notice that Microsoft cannot get even the most basic terminology right, I cannot assume that their floating point implementation is correct for all purposes.

Comment: The majority of the floating point implementation is in hardware, though, so I doubt there's much to worry about. In any case nowhere on the documentation page for `Double.Epsilon` does it say "machine epsilon" which is the correct term for what you want, so I'm not sure it's that confusing.

Comment: @Alexandre, @Rup: ...and IEEE-754 doesn't define "machine epsilon" at all, so the fact that `double.Epsilon` and machine epsilon aren't the same thing seems completely orthogonal to whether or not Microsoft's FP implementation is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Just hard-code the value:

```
const double e1 = 2.2204460492503131e-16;
```

or use the power of two:

```
static readonly double e2 = Math.Pow(2, -52);
```

or use your definition (more or less):

```
static readonly double e3 = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(1.0) + 1L) - 1.0;
```

And see [Wikipedia: machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

Answer (score 0):

LAPACK + DLAMCH, 64-bit INTEL processor, C#:

```
var pp = double.Epsilon; // pp = 4.94065645841247E-324
double p = NativeMethods.MachinePrecision('S'); // =DLAMCH('S') 
p = 2.2250738585072014E-308
double.MinValue = -1.7976931348623157E+308
double.MaxValue =  1.7976931348623157E+308
```

Answer (score -2):

Ref. the routine in Meonester's:
Actually the value of machEps on exit from the do ... while loop is such that 1+machEps == 1.
To obtain the machine epsilon we must go back to the previous value, by adding the following after the loop:
machEps *= 2.0D;
This will return 2.2204460492503131e-16 in agreement with the recommendation in Microsoft's documentation for Double.Epsilon.